# Codeigniter : search pagination not limit by post method?

Tags: php, codeigniter

**My Controller :**

```
public function search()
    {   
        $data['category_name'] = $this->model_products->dis_category();
            $this->load->view('layout/header', $data);



            $keyword = ''; // default when no term in session or POST
            if ($this->input->post('search'))
            {
                // use the term from POST and set it to session
                $keyword = $this->input->post('search');
                $this->session->set_userdata('keyword', $keyword);
            }
            elseif ($this->session->userdata('keyword'))
            {
                // if term is not in POST use existing term from session
                $keyword = $this->session->userdata('keyword');
            }

            $data['otherproduct'] = $this->model_products->other_prodects();
            $data['otherproduct2'] = $this->model_products->other_prodects2();

            //Pagination init
            $config['base_url']     = base_url().'search/';
            $config['total_rows']   = $this->model_products->num_rows($keyword);
            $config['per_page']     = 10;
            $config['uri_segment']  = 2;
            $config['num_links']    = 2;
            //custom pigination
            $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="tsc_pagination tsc_paginationA tsc_paginationA01">';
            $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
            $config['prev_link'] = 'Prev';
            $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
            $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="current"><a href="#">';
            $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
            $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

            $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';

            $config['first_link'] = 'First';
            $config['last_link'] = 'Last';

            $this->pagination->initialize($config);

            $data['search'] = $this->model_products->SearchResult($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(2,0),$keyword);

            $this->load->vars($data);

            $this->load->view('layout/resault', $data);
            $this->load->view('layout/footer');
    }
```

My Model :

```
function SearchResult($perPage,$uri,$keyword)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->like('pro_part',$keyword);
        $this->db->or_like('pro_description',$keyword);
        $this->db->or_like('pro_name',$keyword);


        $this->db->order_by('pro_part','asc');
        $getData = $this->db->get('products', $perPage, $uri);

        return $getData->result_array();

    }


    function num_rows($keyword){

            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->where_in("'pro_part' like '%$keyword'");
            $this->db->or_where_in("'pro_name' like '%$keyword'");

            $query = $this->db->get('products');
            return $query->num_rows();  
        }
```

My View :

> Featured Products </span></h2>-->
>                                     Results for "session->userdata('word') ;?>"
>
> ```
>                       <?php if(count($search) > 0):?>
>                           <?php foreach ($search as $row) :?>
>                             <div class="span13 product">
>
>                                 <div>
>                                     <figure>
>                                         <?php if(!empty($row['pro_image'])): ?>
>                                       <a href="<?= site_url("view")."?productdetail=".$row['pro_id'];?>"><img
> ```
>
> src="template/images/products/"  alt="image" />
>
> ```
>                                           <?php else :?>
>                                           <img alt="image" src="http://placehold.it/50x35"> </a>
>                                           <?php endif;?>
>
>                                     </figure>
>                                     <div class="detail">
>                                         <span>$<?php echo $row['pro_price'];?></span>
>                                         <h4><?php echo $row['pro_part'];?></h4>
>                                       <h4><?php echo $row['pro_name'];?></h4>
>                                         <div class="icon">
>                                             <a href="<?=site_url("add-to-cart")."/".$row['pro_id'];?>" class="one
> ```
>
> tooltip" title="Add to cart">
>
> ```
>                                         </div>
>                                     </div>
>                                 </div>
>
>                             </div>
>                           <?php endforeach;?>
>                           <div class="span12">
>                            <div class="pagination clearfix">
>                                     <!--<p>Items 1 to 9 of 12 total</p>-->
>                                     <ul class="clearfix">
>                                         <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
>                                     </ul>
>                                 </div>
>                           </div>
>
>                           <?php else: ?>
>                           <div class="span12">
>                               We did not find results for"<?php echo $this->session->userdata('word') ;?>"
>
>                               <div class="search_other">
>                               <span>Other Products</span>
>
>                               </div>
>                               <div class="container">
>                               <div class="row">
>
>
>                               <section class="responsive slider">
> <?php foreach($otherproduct as $row ): ?>   
>    <div>
>
>                                 <div class="span13 product">
>
>                                     <figure>
>                                         <?php if(!empty($row->pro_image)): ?>
>                                       <a href="<?= site_url("view")."?productdetail=".$row->pro_id;?>"><img
> ```
>
> src="template/images/products/pro_image ;?>"  alt="image" />
>
> ```
>                                           <?php else :?>
>                                           <img alt="image" src="http://placehold.it/50x35"> </a>
>                                           <?php endif;?>
>
>                                     </figure>
>                                     <div class="detail">
>                                         <span>$<?php echo $row->pro_price;?></span>
>                                         <h4><?php echo $row->pro_part;?></h4>
>                                       <h4><?php echo $row->pro_name;?></h4>
>                                         <div class="icon">
>                                             <a href="<?=site_url("add-to-cart")."/".$row->pro_id;?>" class="one
> ```
>
> tooltip" title="Add to cart">
>
> ```
>                                         </div>
>                                     </div>
>
>
>                               </div>
>
>     </div>
>
>   <?php endforeach;?>
>   <?php foreach($otherproduct2 as $row ): ?>   
>    <div>
>
>                                 <div class="span13 product">
>
>                                     <figure>
>                                         <?php if(!empty($row->pro_image)): ?>
>                                       <a href="<?= site_url("view")."?productdetail=".$row->pro_id;?>"><img
> ```
>
> src="template/images/products/pro_image ;?>"  alt="image" />
>
> ```
>                                           <?php else :?>
>                                           <img alt="image" src="http://placehold.it/50x35"> </a>
>                                           <?php endif;?>
>
>                                     </figure>
>                                     <div class="detail">
>                                         <span>$<?php echo $row->pro_price;?></span>
>                                         <h4><?php echo $row->pro_part;?></h4>
>                                       <h4><?php echo $row->pro_name;?></h4>
>                                         <div class="icon">
>                                             <a href="<?=site_url("add-to-cart")."/".$row->pro_id;?>" class="one
> ```
>
> tooltip" title="Add to cart">
>
> ```
>                                         </div>
>                                     </div>
>
>
>                               </div>
>
>     </div>
>
>   <?php endforeach;?>
>     <div>
>
>
>   </section>
>
>
>
>                               </div>
>                               </div>
>                           </div>
>                       <?php endif; ?>
>                         </div>
>
>                     </div>
>                 </div>
> ```

My problem is result pagination count all my row in database not limit by post methods.

Comment: That's a lot of code to expect us to go through. By the looks of it there are some basic errors. The main one I think is single quoted identifiers instead of backticks.

Comment: Now what is your current problem? The pagination is not working by number.right?You have given `$config['per_page']     = 10;` But not working?

Comment: Refer this -> http://www.iprogrammerindia.in/pagination-search-and-field-sorting-in-codeigniter/

Comment: $config['per_page'] = 10; is working but the result pagination count all my row in database not limit by methods post.

Answer (score 0):

change your model where_in to where , where_in is used for array which will result null in your case so it is not using the condition

```
function num_rows($keyword){

            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->where_in("'pro_part' like '%$keyword'");
            $this->db->or_where_in("'pro_name' like '%$keyword'");

            $query = $this->db->get('products');
            return $query->num_rows();  
        }
```

to

```
function num_rows($keyword){

            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->where("'username' like '%$keyword%'");
            $this->db->or_where("'full_name' like '%$keyword%'");

            $query = $this->db->get('cms_users');
            //$query1 = $this->db->last_query();
            //print_r($query1);
            return $query->result_array();  
        }
```

Comment: I get this error : Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in D:\WEBSITE\htdocs\online-store\system\libraries\Pagination.php on line 408
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Unsupported operand types

Filename: libraries/Pagination.php

Line Number: 408

Backtrace:

Comment: Oops sorry change return $query->result_array();  to $query->num_rows();

Comment: link page number not display